Error launching Azure CLI: executable file not found in PATH
Getting this error when trying to run terraform plan -out main.tfplan
unable to build authorizer for Resource Manager API: could not configure AzureCli Authorizer: could not parse Azure CLI version: launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in %PATH%

Does anyone have a fix for this?
I didn't try anything except for looking online to see if there is a fix for this error.
data.tf being the cause of this was being mentioned, but that is not present in my branch.

Found a helpful guide, haven't created a workspace yet, but to resolve this issue this is what needs to be done first. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/azure-get-started/azure-remote

terraform uses Azure cli for Azure resources. You may check your current version: az --version. If you do not have it, you may install it from these sources: How to install the Azure CLI
Here you can find the explanation of the authentication: Azure Provider: Authenticating using the Azure CLI
